# issues with CGContextRef

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, quartz-2d, cgcontext

I am working with drawing project, as we know to draw something we need to get call this function, `UIGraphicsGetCurrentcontext`, So I am also calling it wherever, I need it, either its clear, or erase . What I am doing is in every function, I am calling it this way

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurentContext()
```

What I want to know, is whether I get the same context whenever I call this function? whether the pointer points to same context?

Because my eraser works in some cases and fails in some cases.

Below is my eraser function

```
- (void)erase
{
    [m_curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect); 
}
```

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Hello friends, can anyone suggest me something in this regard

Comment: what do you want... i didn't get you.
do you want to make an eraser ?

Comment: Give us the case in which it works and case in which it does not. However, you cannot use UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() out side main thread.

Comment: When your method fails? what are those conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `UIGraphicsGetCurentContext()` inside of the drawRect method, outside of that it will not be configured with a valid context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom view and write your erase() method code in the `drawRect` method.